# Right click menu on windowsXP in background: new file types

Tags: windows-xp, registry

I would like to remove all file types but one from right click menu resulting on right-clicking on background in windows XP (and then going to "new").
I tried HKCR ->Directory ->Background->sheelex in the registry and there is "new" item but it just have one value.
The problem is I have like 20 file types there but I only need one to save time looking for that .txt every time (to be sure no random stuff is added to new file, I am editing extension myself every time anyway).
Where do I find content of this menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic is explained here: *Extending the New Submenu*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144101(v=vs.85).aspx#new

To do the opposite, you need to search the registry for below key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.XXX\ShellNew
```

Where `XXX` is a file extension name. e.g.: `bmp`, `rtf`, `txt`, etc.
You can do this by using below batch file.

```
@ECHO OFF
REG EXPORT HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT "%TEMP%\REGLIST.TMP"
FIND /I "\SHELLNEW]" "%TEMP%\REGLIST.TMP"
DEL "%TEMP%\REGLIST.TMP"
PAUSE
```

It will show something like this.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.doc\ShellNew]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dpp\ShellNew]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.Hxs\Hxs\ShellNew]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rtf\ShellNew]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip\ShellNew]
```

Note that not all `ShellNew` subkey will be displayed on the `New` submenu since it must follow the requirements as decribed in the above link.

To remove the *New File* menu entry, delete the `ShellNew` registry subkey.

For example, if the file extension name is `dpp`, then registry key would be:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dpp\ShellNew
```

And to remove the `ShellNew` subkey, you can use *Registry Editor* or the command line *REG* tool.
For *REG* example:

```
REG DELETE HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dpp\ShellNew
```